# SMTP use in PHPMailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, phpmailer

I am using the last version of PHPMailer to send emails from my web. I can send some emails without SMTP parameters, but i need to give the SMTP configuration to my object PHPMailer(). The functions that sends this emails are in the same file.

Why some emails could need SMTP configurations and not others?

Regards

```
function sendEmailWithoutSMTP(){

    $bodyIntern = file_get_contents('emails/myemail.html');
    
    $mailIntern = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mailIntern->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    try {

        //Recipients
        $mailIntern->AddAddress('myemail@myemail.com', 'My address');
        $mailIntern->SetFrom('myemail@myemail.com', 'My address');
        $mailIntern->AddReplyTo('myemail@myemail.com', 'My address');
        
        //Content
        $mailIntern->Subject = 'My subject';
        $mailIntern->AltBody = '';
        $mailIntern->MsgHTML($bodyIntern);
        $mailIntern->Send();
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        //echo $e->errorMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
          //echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function sendEmailWithSMTP($email){

    require_once 'smtp/getsmtp.php';

    $smtp= get_smtp($email); 
        
    $bodyClient = file_get_contents('emails/myotheremail.html');
    
    $mailClient = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mailClient->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    try {
        
        //Server settings
        $mailClient->IsSMTP();
        $mailClient->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
        $mailClient->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mailClient->SMTPSecure = $smtp["secure"];
        $mailClient->Host = $smtp["host"];
        $mailClient->Username = $smtp["username"];
        $mailClient->Password = $smtp["pass"];
        $mailClient->Port = $smtp["port"];
        $mailClient->Timeout= 30;

        //Recipients
        $mailClient->AddAddress('myemail@myemail.com', 'My address');
        $mailClient->SetFrom('myemail@myemail.com', 'My address');
        $mailClient->AddReplyTo('myemail@myemail.com', 'My address');
        
        //Content
        $mailClient->Subject = 'My subject';
        $mailClient->AltBody = '';
        $mailClient->MsgHTML($bodyIntern);
        $mailClient->Send();

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        //echo $e->errorMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $this->sendEmailWithoutSMTP();
            
}
```

Comment: Every SMTP server is a castle, some with their drawbridges wide open, some with archers, moats and secret handshakes. (There’s probably other cool castle security stuff that I’m missing, sorry.) So depending on which SMTP server you are connecting to, there’s different settings needed. The most likely candidate is `SMTPSecure` which handles SSL/TLS and is required by some, optional for others, and not available for (hopefully) a minority.

Comment: It is strange because I am sending this emails by the same server...

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer has several different ways of sending messages.

First of all there is the default, which uses PHP's built-in `mail()` function behind the scenes. This does not use SMTP, but hands the message to a `sendmail` program using a path set in your php.ini file. This sending method does not require any SMTP setup, and SMTP-related params (e.g. `Username`, `Host`) will just be ignored, but it does require that you have a local mail server.

`isSendmail()` is like a manually-constructed equivalent to PHP's built-in function, but it gives you a bit more control if you are using some unusual local mail server. Generally you should not use this.

If you call `isSMTP()`, it will try to use SMTP directly, and all of the SMTP parameters will be used. Even if you do have a local mail server, this is the recommended route because it's faster, safer, and easier to debug. If you need to send through a remote mail server (such as gmail), this is your only option.

So in your code, the first function is sending using `mail()`, and the second uses SMTP.

Comment: Thanks Synchro, your answer is very clear. Maybe you can help me with this problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544025/phpmailer-dont-work-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate. Thanks for PHPMailer library by the way!