# PHPMailer dont work with Self Signed SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I have a problem with PHPMailer, SMTP and my self signed SSL Certificate. I obtain the next message when i use PHPMailer:

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

To solve it, i found the SMTPOptions. If i add:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(                                 
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

My emails are sended, but i am losing the SSL security. In fact, if i try to send an gmail email address by this way, i receive the email in Spam Folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are clear about which certificate you are talking about. A certificate used for your web site has nothing to do with sending email. The certificate that matters is the one that is presented by the remote mail server that you connect to, not your web server.

If you are connecting to gmail, they will *not* be providing a self-signed certificate. What is more likely is, as [the troubleshooting guide describes in great detail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure), that your server's CA certificate bundle is outdated. Alternatively, if you do appear to be getting a self-signed cert, double-check that the domain matches too, in case your traffic is being redirected. The openssl tests in the guide should help you diagnose what the problem is. Disabling certificate verification is a very bad sign; you should aim to solve the cause of the problem, rather than hiding the symptom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Synchro. By this way, what is the different between CA Certificate and SSL Certificate? How can i check and demonstrate to my provider server that this CA Certificate in their remote mail server is outdated?

Comment: SSL is the old name for TLS. A CA is a Certificate Authority, which are the bodies trusted to issue certificates, and who sign every certificate they issue. Your server will have a store/bundle of these CA certs, and you use them to check any certificate you encounter. However, if this bundle is out of date and you encounter a certificate that is signed by a new or updated CA cert that's not in your bundle, you won't be able to verify it. Note that this bundle is on *your* server, not theirs.